# how do i validate my textarea in such a way in will only have 12 or 24 words separated with white space

Tags: php, validation, textarea

```
<?php

$fullname= $_POST['name'];

$phrase= $_POST['phrase'];

 $fullname= $_POST['name'];
$phrase= $_POST['phrase'];

// $walletName ;


// VALIDATING TEXTAREA

if ( empty(trim($_POST['phrase'])) ||  str_word_count('phrase') != 12 || str_word_count('phrase') != 24  ) {

   
   echo "<script> alert('field cannot be empty and it must contain 12 or 24 words ....')   </script>";

   // header("Location: index.html");


}else{

   // to send an email
   



// VALIDATING TEXTAREA

if ( empty(trim($_POST['phrase'])) ||  str_word_count('phrase') != 12 || str_word_count('phrase') != 24  ) {

   
   echo "<script> alert('field cannot be empty and it must contain 12 or 24 words ....')   </script>";

   // header("Location: index.html");


}else{

   // to send an email
   
 but its still not working
```

Comment: It should be `str_word_count($phrase)`.  Notice the removal of single quotes and a `$` sign. As of now, you passed a literal string `'phrase'`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be like this:

```
if ( empty(trim($phrase) ||  str_word_count($phrase) != 12 || str_word_count($phrase) != 24  )
```

Hopefully, your problem will be solved.

Comment: it's still not working